# How to properly set a range preceding code to delete rows in a table column

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to set up some code to delete a number of rows in a table based on a particular word/number in a table column, I come up with the error

```
Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed.
```

I have used code almost identical to the following code in another workbook without any issues. I changed the sheet number, the table name, the column name, and the textbox name to match the new workbook information.

```
Dim intLastRow As Integer
Dim strDelete As String
Dim rngFindID As Range
Dim intAnswer As Integer

Sheet1.Activate

Set rngFindID = Range("tblMaster[Job #]").Find(txtJobid.Value, LookIn:=LookIn = xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If rngFindID Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Job # doesn't exist in records."
Else
    intAnswer = MsgBox("Job # found. Delete?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Record")
    If intAnswer = yes Then
        strDelete = txtJobid.Value
        intLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = intLastRow To 1 Step -1
            If Cells(i, 1) = strDelete Then Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        Next i
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
End If
```

I want this code to delete certain rows based on the value in cells in the Job # column. The line

```
Set rngFindID = Range("tblMaster[Job #]").Find(txtJobid.Value, LookIn:=LookIn = xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

is highlighted with the previously mentioned error code.

This is my first time posting on this forum. Please let me know if anymore information is required.

Comment: I corrected a typo within the For i… portion. It should be "If Cells(i,1)" not "If Cells (1,1)". Regardless, I end up with the same error.
In addition, I noticed that when I type "tblmaster[job #]", it isn't autocorrected into the proper capitals used in the table and column names.

Comment: Is this a typo? `LookIn:=LookIn = xlValues`

Comment: Also shouldn't it just be `Range("tblMaster[Job]")`?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. Thank you.

Comment: As for your second comment, I'm not sure. It's been several years since I've used vba. The column I'm referencing is called "Job #". I'm supposed to use the full name of the column header, am I not?

Comment: By changing the column name to just [Job] from [Job #] and also changing the same in the code, I got by the code 1004 error. However, I now have an entirely different problem on my hands. The code I'm attempting to use to delete rows stopped working. Any ideas? Or should I do a separate post altogether to find an answer?

Comment: The problem was somewhere in my if then statement. Getting rid of the statement and just going straight into the deletion code bypassed the issue. The last message box wasn't vital, and I'm pressed for time. For now, it'll do. I greatly appreciate your help, SJR!